# How to get user's first name(or any data) from Parse.com using Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.android

Good day everyone. I am pretty new to Mobile Development using C# and XAMARIN. My problem is I am trying to get the current user's first name from Parse.com database and display it on a textview, but I am getting nothing. Here's my code for getting the user data:

```
public async void getData(){
        var ProfileName = await ParseObject.GetQuery ("User")
            .WhereEqualTo ("FirstName", ParseUser.CurrentUser).FindAsync ();
        string ProfName = ProfileName.ToString ();
        name.Text = ProfName; //name.Text is the text view

    }
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: var user = await ParseUser.CurrentUser.FetchAsync();

Comment: i appreciate you for commenting and noticing my question but I have found a solution before I read your comment, but thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me again. After diving deep down into stackoverflow, I have stumbled upon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454341/c-sharp-desktop-app-and-parse-com). It is somewhat similar to what I'm looking for and it solved my problem. So here's my modified code that works, it display the First name of the currently logged in user.

```
public void getData(){
        string parseUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Get<string> ("FirstName");
        name.Text = parseUser;
    }
```